# Bulk Record Update with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have two tables in a SQL Server 2008 environment with the following structure

```
Table1
- ID
- DescriptionID
- Description

Table2
- ID
- Description
```

Table1.DescriptionID maps to Table2.ID. However, I do not need it any more. I would like to do a bulk update to set the Description property of Table1 to the value associated with it in Table2. In other words I want to do something like this:

```
UPDATE
  [Table1] 
SET
  [Description]=(SELECT [Description] FROM [Table2] t2 WHERE t2.[ID]=Table1.DescriptionID)
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the appropriate approach. Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: That's some magic. I used it in a migration for a single table.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Your way is correct, and here is another way you can do it:

```
update      Table1
set         Description = t2.Description
from        Table1 t1
inner join  Table2 t2
on          t1.DescriptionID = t2.ID
```

The nested select is the long way of just doing a join.

Comment: I like to use the alias in the UPDATE. No difference really but makes it clear which table in the FROM I'm actually updating. Useful for self joins etc

Comment: @gbn: You can't set an alias for a table that is just after the update clause (`UPDATE thisTableCannotHaveAnAlias`) ...

Comment: You don't alias there, you refer to the alias you specify in the from clause. Like my answer and in an older one by me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins/982947#982947 and on MSDN http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx where you can `UPDATE table_alias` "table_alias: The alias specified in the FROM clause representing the table or view from which the rows are to be updated."

Answer (score 33):

Your approach is OK

Maybe slightly clearer (to me anyway!)

```
UPDATE
  T1
SET
  [Description] = t2.[Description]
FROM
   Table1 T1
   JOIN
   [Table2] t2 ON t2.[ID] = t1.DescriptionID
```

Both this and your query should run the same performance wise because it is the same query, just laid out differently.

Comment: +1 For telling him perf is the same.  Yours is easier to read by far, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this through a regular `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`

```
UPDATE T1
SET Description = T2.Description
   FROM Table1 T1
      JOIN Table2 T2
         ON T2.ID = T1.DescriptionId
```

Comment: This looks exactly like gbn's answer, yet @Tocco says this one is wrong and the other is correct. What gives?

Answer (score 3):

Or you can simply update without using join like this:

```
Update t1 set  t1.Description = t2.Description from @tbl2 t2,tbl1 t1
where t1.ID= t2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you posted in your question is one way to do it. Most things in SQL have more than one way to do it.

```
UPDATE
  [Table1] 
SET
  [Description]=(SELECT [Description] FROM [Table2] t2 WHERE t2.[ID]=Table1.DescriptionID)
```

If you are planning on running this on a PROD DB, it is best to create a snapshot or mirror of it first and test it out. Verify the data ends up as you expect for a couple records. And if you are satisfied, run it on the real DB.