# How to update multiple columns of MySQL table using the data of same table

Tags: mysql

```
+--------+------+-------+-------+
| C1     |  C2  |  C3       C4  |
+--------+------+-------+------+
| Value1 | 1234 |  9876 |   A1  |
| Value2 | 1234 |  9876 |   A1  |
| Value3 | 1234 |  9876 |   A1  |
| Value4 | 1234 |  9876 |   A1  |
| Value1 |      |       |   B1  |
| Value2 |      |       |   B1  |
| Value3 |      |       |   B1  |
| Value4 |      |       |   B1  |
+-------+------+-------+------- +
```

I have a MySQL table with the above structure.I want to update the last four rows for column C2 & C3 with the same data as in the first 4 rows of column C2 & C3.This update has to be done using the same table multiple column data.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I guess you could try something

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Update table set c2=(Select C2 from table where c4=A1) where c1=value1
```

and so on by changing column values in inner query or using cursor.

Based upon this:

[Bulk Record Update with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629088/bulk-record-update-with-sql)

you can do as:

```
update      Table
set         C2= c2
from        Table t1
inner join  Table t2
on          t1.c1 = t2.c1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,is there any option for bulk update? Updating all the 4 columns at once?