# Help Needed SQL - Parsing through a 2 Lac+ records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Customer table with 200.000+ records which i have to loop through and check for a condition(on a particular column) and update the "IsPremiumUser" Column to TRUE. 
what is the best way to go about it?

I see i can achieve this in two ways

1. Use Join and Update
2. Loop through each record and update it.

I am using SQL Server2008.

Update: I did not mean looping through records using C# or Java but in the SQL Itself. I am looking for ways to reduce the execution time as there are more than 200.000 records. It is taking 20 mins using update+join

Update2: Here are the queries.

```
MERGE pref.personpreference AS T
USING (SELECT PR.PersonID,PR.PersonroleId from personrole PR ) as S
ON (T.PersonRoleID = S.PersonRoleID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET T.SDRPERSONID = S.PersonId;



UPDATE PP 
SET PP.SDRPersonID = PR.PersonID
FROM PREF.PersonPreference PP JOIN PersonRole PR
ON PP.PersonRoleID = PR.PersonRoleID
```

Notes: Merge is taking 17 mins and update 20 mins to execute. But i see the number of records modified differ by some 1000 between these statements.

Comment: Can you post your update statement that's taking 20+minutes to run? <strike>How many records is it updating?</strike> Just found out what [2Lakh][1] is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use database commands instead of looping through a bunch of records and issuing UPDATE statements every time a row meets your condition. It will be much, much faster and only 2-3 lines of SQL instead of 10-20 lines of java/c#/whatever-code.

Have a look at [SQL update query using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins) for an example.

Comment: I did not mean looping through records using C# or Java but in the SQL Itself. I was just looking for ways to reduce the execution time as there are more than 2Lac records. It is taking 20mins using update+join

Comment: Ok, but looping through even in SQL will take mor time then the 20 minutes for update+join. Do you ahve appropriate indexes set up?

Answer (score 1):

If the column is on the same table then use an UPDATE statement with a WHERE condition in which you will define the rows to be updated.

```
UPDATE Customers
SET isPremiumUser = 1 -- true
WHERE some_column operator some_condition
```

eg

```
WHERE friend_members > 10
```