# SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a record in oracle SQL developer by using Joins.
Following is my query-

```
UPDATE system_info set field_value = 'NewValue' 
FROM system_users users 
JOIN system_info info ON users.role_type = info.field_desc 
where users.user_name = 'uname'
```

However, when I tried to execute it, I got following error-

```
Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 
              00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended"
```

I tried removing JOINS

```
UPDATE system_info info 
SET info.field_value = 'NewValue' 
FROM system_users users 
where users.user_name = 'uname' AND users.role_type = info.field_desc
```

but still having same error
can anybody tell me the error reason and solution

Comment: I think your sqlDevelepor executed the previous line. put a semi colon before and after your sql statement and try again

Comment: I tried your solution, but not working for me

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Oracle does not allow joining tables in an UPDATE statement. You need to rewrite your statement with a co-related sub-select

Something like this:

```
UPDATE system_info
SET field_value = 'NewValue' 
WHERE field_desc IN (SELECT role_type 
                     FROM system_users 
                     WHERE user_name = 'uname')
```

For a complete description on the (valid) syntax of the UPDATE statement, please read the manual:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10008.htm#i2067715

Comment: Seeing this for the first time since it was lined to in a Comment (in Nov. 2016). This is not true: Oracle does allow joins in an UPDATE, but there are some restrictions (obvious ones, demanded by logic, not by Oracle). Where does this very widespread misconception that Oracle doesn't allow one to update a join come from?  How the update with joins work is discussed for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001180/update-with-join-syntax-for-oracle-database

Comment: @mathguy: Oracle allows to update a derived table (sub-query) which can under certain restrictions use a join (mainly: the query needs to be a "key preserved table"). But that is something different then simply joining the target table to another table (which has typically less restrictions in those DBMS that support this)

Comment: Exactly right - which is not the same as "Oracle does not allow joining tables in an UPDATE statement." I know that, and clearly you know that too; now search through SO and see how many times people make that statement, even in (many) cases when updating through a join would work perfectly fine, if only people used the proper syntax and they had the proper unique constraint in the source table. I just created a Documentation article to discuss this, we'll see if it is approved.

Comment: Mentioned link says "Page not found"

Answer (score 107):

Semicolon `;` on the end of command had caused the same error on me.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO U_USERS_TABLE (USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES ("
                + "'" + txtUsername.Text + "',"
                + "'" + txtPassword.Text + "',"
                + "'" + txtFirstname.Text + "',"
                + "'" + txtLastname.Text + "');"; <== Semicolon in "" is the cause.
                                                      Removing it will be fine.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ouch!  I had this problem, but didn't realize it, because including the ";" on the SqlPlus command line works just fine.

Comment: i too had a same problem . its very hard to find it exact issue thanks it helped me a lot

Comment: Very helpful, this was the mistake ";", Thanks

Comment: spent 3 hrs then saw this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your query should look like

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

You can check the below question for help

- [SQL update query using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)?

Comment: ANSI joins are supported by Oracle

Comment: @Sathya: but not in an UPDATE statement.

Comment: you can check the link (SQL update query using joins?),it has your answer

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly the case of actual context of this question, but this exception can be reproduced by the next query:

```
update users set dismissal_reason='he can't and don't want' where userid=123
```

Single quotes in words `can't` and `don't` broke the string. 
In case string have only one inside quote e.g. 'he don't want' oracle throws more relevant **quoted string not properly terminated** error, but in case of two **SQL command not properly ended** is thrown.

Summary: check your query for double single quotes.

Answer (score -9):

its very true on oracle as well as sql is "users"  is a reserved words just change it ,
it will serve u the best if u like change it to this

```
UPDATE system_info set field_value = 'NewValue'
```

`FROM system_users users JOIN system_info info ON users.role_type = info.field_desc 
where users.user_name = 'uname'`

Comment: `users` is **not** a reserved word! `user` however is a reserved word. But the real problem is, that Oracle does not allow FROM or JOIN in an UPDATE statement.