# SQL JOIN with UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

i have two tables TBL_TEST1 and TBL_TEST2 with columns DISTRICT and NAME in both tables, there are data in both tables in column DISTRICT which are same i want to update TBL_TEST2  all NAME column values to 'Done' where in TBL_TEST2 table in its DISTRICT value '1' found in both tables.

below are my tables with query

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_TEST1

DISTRICT    NAME
1           Rashid
2           Ramish
1           Ali
1           Karim
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_TEST2

DISTRICT    NAME
1           DDD
2           DDDY
3           DDDD7
1           DD1
1           DDD4
```

When i try

```
  UPDATE TBL_TEST2 SET TBL_TEST2.NAME = 'DONE'  FROM TBL_TEST2 INNER JOIN TBL_TEST1 ON TBL_TEST2.DISTRICT = TBL_TEST1.DISTRICT WHERE TBL_TEST2.DISTRICT = '1'
```

i receive error msg below

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

i tested codes which are in other posts, i am asking that however my code is correct why i am still receiving that error msg

Comment: You tagged your question with `mysql` but the error message suggests that you are in fact using `oracle` which uses a different syntax for update with joins. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle

Comment: Another SO question that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940471/sql-error-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended

Comment: i test codes which are in other posts, i want to know what is wrong with my code that i am still receiving that error msg

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find that syntax?

Comment: i tested the code in blow post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server

Comment: @MelladQarizada That question is for Microsoft SQL Server not Oracle and not applicable here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your join is wrong  (You are using FROM in UPDATE) 
This syntax for JOIN is not for ORACLE

> ```
> UPDATE TBL_TEST2 
> SET TBL_TEST2.NAME = 'DONE'  
> FROM TBL_TEST2 
> INNER JOIN TBL_TEST1 ON TBL_TEST2.DISTRICT = TBL_TEST1.DISTRICT 
> WHERE TBL_TEST2.DISTRICT = '1';
> ```

In ORACLE A simple way for update joined table is based on the use the the joined select as a table

```
  UPDATE ( 
  SELECT TBL_TEST2.NAME AS OLD_VALUE
  FROM TBL_TEST2 
  INNER JOIN TBL_TEST1 ON TBL_TEST2.DISTRICT = TBL_TEST1.DISTRICT 
  WHERE TBL_TEST2.DISTRICT = '1' ) T
  SET T.OLD_VALUE = 'DONE'  ;
```

Comment: also it is good to mention that in Oracle your tables need to have relation with each other in order to update a join result between them!!