# SQL left join unable to delete rows?

Tags: sql, windows, oracle

So i am trying to delete some rows in a left joined table using the following code in sql:

```
DELETE gw_svd_prefix_assignment
FROM gw_svd_prefix_assignment svdp
left join assyst_view av
on upper(svdp.user_name) = upper(av.usr_sc)
where upper(av.usr_sc) IS NULL
commit;
```

but i am getting this error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DELETE gw_svd_prefix_assignment
FROM gw_svd_prefix_assignment svdp
left join assyst_view av
on upper(svdp.user_name) = upper(av.usr_sc)
where upper(av.usr_sc) IS NULL
commit
Error at Command Line : 2 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940471/sql-error-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah my apologies, Gordon's answer should do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not support that syntax.  `UPDATE` and `DELETE` only work on one table . . . the `FROM` clause cannot contain multiple tables.

Instead, put the logic in the `WHERE` clause:

```
delete from gw_svd_prefix_assignment svdp
    where not exists (select 1
                      from assyst_view av
                      where upper(svdp.user_name) = upper(av.usr_sc)
                     );
```

Comment: COOL! Thanks for your help! Worked perfectly fine. :)

Comment: @AbdallahQaraeen - did you try to add the `;` first, as suggested by someone in the Comments? That was obviously missing from what you posted.

Comment: @AbdallahQaraeen - I just tested, and Oracle **does** support deleting with JOIN; I tested a case exactly like yours, with a left join and where what is deleted are exactly the rows that wouldn't match in an inner join. I also just created a Documentation article "Updates with Join" under the `Oracle Database` tag addressing the misconception that Oracle does not support UPDATE with joins.