# Powershell ORA-00933 Error when executing sql queries from .sql file

Tags: powershell, ora-00933

I have a SQL file and I'm trying to execute queries in it via PowerShell. But even I can execute one query, I can not when adding that file multiple queries like below.

```
GRANT SELECT ON table TO user1;
GRANT SELECT ON table TO user2;
```

```
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "ORA-00933: SQL komutu tam doğru olarak sona ermedi"   
At line:23 char:5   
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : OracleException
```

```
$query=Get-Content C:\Users\asdg.sql | Out-String
write-host $query


$command.CommandText = $query
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader()

while ($reader.Read()) {
    $reader.GetString(0)
    }
```

English Error:

> *SQL command did not end properly*

Comment: Did you already check this? https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended/

Comment: There is one more answer of this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940471/sql-error-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended

Comment: yeah but removing ";" doesnt work neither. when there is one query like GRANT SELECT ON table TO user1 is fine but when there are two or more dont work.

Comment: Remove Grant and run it.

`GRANT SELECT ON table TO user1;
SELECT ON table TO user2;`

Comment: sorry, thats not work either.. there arent no grants only but there should be queries like below.

ALTER TRIGGER x DISABLE;

UPDATE table
   SET column = 1
 WHERE t IN ('y');

COMMIT;

Comment: Try this, `ALTER TRIGGER x DISABLE; UPDATE table SET column = 1 WHERE t = 'y'; COMMIT;`