# what does the error "ORA-00933:" mean in my situation

Tags: sql, oracle

I am just a student and I am trying to get a table working but have tried everything I could only to end up with an error.

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Could anyone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
    idnumber VARCHAR2(8),
    firstname VARCHAR2(20),
    lastname VARCHAR2(20),
    dateofbirth DATE,
    address VARCHAR2(20),
    email VARCHAR2(20),
    programme VARCHAR2(5),
    points number(3),

    PRIMARY KEY (idnumber)
);

INSERT INTO student 
VALUES ('D1234567', 'Student ONE', 'TWO THREE', DATE '2000-05-10',
        'Thetown, the address', 'd1234567@mydit.ie', 'DT228', '380'),
       ('D2345678', 'Student TWO', 'FOUR FIVE', DATE '2000-04-10',
        'Thetown, the address', 'd2345678@mydit.ie', 'DT228', '280');

SELECT 
    firstname, lastname
FROM 
    student
WHERE 
    points > 300;
```

Comment: I don't think that is a valid `INSERT` statement. I think it would be easier to just write two separate `INSERT` statements.

Comment: You have several commands there, try them one at a time to find the problem one

Comment: If you change your `ECHO` setting with `set echo on`, then your console output will make it obvious which command is the cause. Then it's a simple matter of looking at the railroad diagrams in the docs. The blank lines in the middle of the `select` look troublesome, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run each of the statements one by one:

Create your table

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
idnumber VARCHAR2(8),
firstname VARCHAR2(20),
lastname VARCHAR2(20),
dateofbirth DATE,
address VARCHAR2(20),
email VARCHAR2(20),
programme VARCHAR2(5),
points number(3),
PRIMARY KEY (idnumber)
);
```

Insert the 1st row

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES
(  
'D1234567',
'Student ONE',
'TWO THREE',
DATE '2000-05-10',
'Thetown,thedress',
'd1234567@mydit.ie',
'DT228',
'380'
);
```

Insert the 2nd row

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES 
(
'D2345678',
'Student TWO',
'FOUR FIVE',
DATE '2000-04-10',
'Thetown,the adress',
'd2345678@mydit.ie',
'DT228',
'280'
);
```

Run the select

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM student
WHERE points > 300;
```

Examples:

1. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d01055a94dce5ed7919a3d26c8a9f73c
2. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d01055a94dce5ed7919a3d26c8a9f73c

Answer (score 3):

That is not valid `insert` syntax. You can only insert one row at a time that way, separating by comma will not work. To do multi-row inserts, use the syntax:

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES ('value', 'another value')
   INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES ('value', 'another value')
   INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES ('value', 'another value')
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

The `select 1 from dual` is required for the subquery needing a select statement. It's no different than doing multiple insert statements, so you might as well just break this into multiple statements unless you are doing thousands of inserts at once.

Comment: "That is not valid insert syntax." is only partly correct. It is valid in standard SQL and most other DBMS I guess, but not in Oracle, because Oracle does not support the full `VALUES` clause. This support has been requested years ago in the Oracles feature requests here: https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4391390/add-support-for-the-values-constructor. It got only few upvotes, because Oracle is successfully hiding their feature requests they call "Database ideas" in the bigger forum, where it is unlikely to be found and hard to search :-(

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I understand this request, but I also understand why Oracle does not want to implement it.  Unlike from other databases Oracle's bind variables also support vector values so you can insert thousands of rows even using single INSERT having single VALUES clause. Also all SQLs have to be parsed and stored in shared pool. such construct might result into SQL having tens of megabytes. or even more.  When parsing such a SQL you need to lock and free huge chunk of shared pool. These situations occasionally lead to outages on production systems, like `cursor: pin S wait on X
` event

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Upvoting ibre5041's comment due to Oracle's *shared everthing* architecture. Promoting this answer in an Oracle context is promoting a solution that would lead to some having protracted response times for multiple reasons. Bad for customer, good for expensive consultant.

Comment: @ibre5041, @Jeff Holt: That is a point I hadn't considered. On the other hand, I doubt very much that above solution or the very common `select 1, 2 from dual union all select 3, 4 from dual union all ...` to circumvent the lack of the full values clause is any better regarding the shared pool.

Comment: `values` is a good shorthand for row generation as long as Oracle doesn't allow to select from nothing. You may insert thousands of rows via single prepared statement in other databases and languages also and it is a common pattern, so no one will use multiple `values` for insert as it may vary (if it is not a SQL-injected code). But as was mentioned above `select 'constant' from dual *<thousand unions>` is not much better option and does not require much imagination to circumvent the limitation.

Answer (score -4):

semicolon (;) is the problem, remove semicolon from last statement and you can get rid of this error, your code's last statement will become

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM student
WHERE points > 300
```

Hope this will work

Comment: This sounds awfully wrong. The semicolon is *meant* to end SQL statements.

Comment: i found a similar answer on internet https://stackoverflow.com/a/33291713/16895959 you can check

Comment: @Himanshukumar yes, and the solution there was not to remove a semicolon. Tools often use semicolons as statement terminators  (or in SQL\*Plus, the SQL terminator character defaults to a semicolon, although it can be set to something else). The issue here is the malformed `values()` clause.