# SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. When using a simple insert

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

When trying to execute the following command through my ASP.NET application, I get an error

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

The statement is:

```
INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (GROUPID, USERID, REMOVED) 
VALUES ('00000000000000000000000000000000', '00000000000000000000000000000000', 0);
```

However, if I run the exact same statement directly against the DB using SQL Developer, it works.

All of the articles I've read about this involve statements using additional criteria like `order by`, `join`, etc.

My connection strings are correct, and other statements are executing fine.

I'm feeding the statement to the database using this code:

```
string command = "insert into SOMETABLE (GROUPID, USERID, REMOVED) values ('00000000000000000000000000000000', '00000000000000000000000000000000', 0);";

int result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command);
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940471/sql-error-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended)

Comment: No, I already looked at that article, but thanks. I've selected the correct answer below. It was a semi colon...

Comment: The marked answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33291713/1260204 is the same, it is to remove the `;` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove semi-colon, here:

```
string command = "insert into SOMETABLE (GROUPID, USERID, REMOVED) values 
('00000000000000000000000000000000', '00000000000000000000000000000000', 0);";
                                                                           ^
                                                                           |
                                                                        here
```

Comment: Ha. Haha. Hahahahaha! Of course that's what it was! I need a vacation... Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy your vacation :)

Comment: Ughhhh, this is a horrendously stupid error, and now I need that vacation too.

Comment: I think I could join you both, @tisaconundrum