# Update Multiple columns in sql and oracle servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Is it possible to get common query for updating multiple columns in table in sql and oracle . Instead of modifying separate queries with provider type.

[Update multiple columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079617/update-multiple-columns-in-sql)

Comment: You've written SQL Server in your title and tagged Oracle? What is your question?

Comment: I need a common query to update multiple columns  of a table in sql server and oracle .

Comment: I'm not well aware on how things work for Oracle, but MERGE should be the way for you to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Oracle is compatible with SQL:2003

You could use

```
MERGE INTO tablename USING table_reference ON (condition)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET column1 = value1 [, column2 = value2 ...]
```

More about MERGE [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29)

Answer (score 0):

The standard ANSI SQL implementation will work with both sql server and oracle

```
UPDATE <TABLE Name>
SET Col1 = ColValue[, Col2 = Col2Value, .....];
```

The only thing that you have to put is a semicolon at the end of update statement, as ";" is mandatory statement terminating operator in oracle, where as it is optional in sql server.

NOTE: The clauses that I put in square brackets ([]) are optional.

NOTE 2: UPDATE..FROM is a properietry syntax used by SQL Server, so it cannot be accepted by oracle..

NOTE 3: UPDATE  SET (col1,col2) = Col1,Col2 is a syntax supported by oracle but not by sql server.

Comment: I think there's no FROM clause in the ANSI SQL.

Comment: @Serge You are correct there is no from clause in the ANSI syntax, my bad.. edited my solution above...