# Updating a column with one query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

To update a column in the database i use the following query

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1
WHERE condition;
```

The problem with this query is that i end up updating one column at a time

i want to update a column by setting a condition and updating a whole column that meets the condition set

An example of what i have tried:

```
UPDATE adggtnz1.lng01_rpt_animrec
SET origin = 'New'
WHERE origin = NULL;
```

and the result of this query is

```
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0  0
```

picture of sample data:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update multiple columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079617/update-multiple-columns-in-sql) The answer with most upvotes (not accepted answer) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Why does NULL = NULL evaluate to false in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server)**

**NO**

WHERE origin = NULL;

**YES**

```
WHERE origin is NULL;
```

> ```
> create table `lng01_rpt_animrec`
> (
>   `origin` varchar(10)
> )
> ```

> ```
> insert into `lng01_rpt_animrec` (`origin`) values
> ('EADD'),
> (null),
> ('EADD'),
> (null),
> (null),
> ('EADD'),
> (null),
> ('EADD'),
> ('EADD');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE
>   lng01_rpt_animrec
> SET
>   origin = 'New'
> WHERE
>   origin is null;
> ```

> ```
> select * from `lng01_rpt_animrec`
> ```
>
> ```
> | origin |
> | :----- |
> | EADD   |
> | New    |
> | EADD   |
> | New    |
> | New    |
> | EADD   |
> | New    |
> | EADD   |
> | EADD   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb9f37a5fe304f5de9afef71692c1da9)*

Answer (score 0):

use `case when` clause for conditional update below query be an example for that

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 =  case when 1<2 then value1 else  value2 end 
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: @MirieriMogaka yes this query will update only  column1 based on condition btw if you share your sample table data and expected updated sample i can help a bit more