# SQL Update  table field x where field y is z

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

How can I insert values into a SQL Server table, into column X, where column Y is Z?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Cities (County_Id) 
WHERE Code >= 10000 AND Code < 20000
VALUE 20
```

Comment: How do the Cities table and the Counties table relate to each other?

Comment: A bit odd that `Cities.County_Id` maps to `Counties.Name` but ok.

Comment: I need to give all cities that have Code between 10000 and 20000, County_Id of for example 20

Comment: Hrmm so you want to insert the Name from County into the County_Id of Cities? Or did you mean the Id of County?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Cities SET County_Id = 20 WHERE Cities.Code >= 10000 AND Cities.Code < 20000
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it sounds like you are trying to do an `UPDATE`, as `INSERT` is used to add a whole new record in the table as opposed to updating one or more existing record(s).

You really should be using `UPDATE-JOIN` instead of `INSERT-SELECT`, if I understand your requirement correctly. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins) StackOverflow thread provides a good example/explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert dbo.Cities( County_Id )
Select Name
From dbo.Counties
Where Counties.Id = 20
    And Exists  (
                Select 1
                From dbo.Cities As C1
                Where C1.County_Id = Counties.Name
                    And C1.Code >= 10000
                    And C1.Code < 20000
                )
```