# how do I update specific rows with values based on a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL update query using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)

Table 1 has 2 columns:

- Has an ID column
- Has a datetime column

Table 2:

- Has an ID column
- Has a datetime column

I need to update the `datetime` column in `table 2` based on the JOIN between table 1 and table 2 on the `ID`.

Example:

```
If table1.id = table2.id, 
update datetime column on table2 
with the datetime column value of table1.
```

Does this make sense?

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Simple [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins) would have set you free ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several options.  A correlated subquery ought to work:

```
UPDATE t2 SET ts = (SELECT ts FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t2.td) WHERE ...
```

This is the easiest method but will be slow for large sets.  The other method is this to do the join directly.  This requires some slightly vendor-specific syntax:

T-SQL:

```
UPDATE table1
SET col1 = t2.col1
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

MySQL:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.col1 = t2.col2
```

(Via: http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.datetime_col = t1.datetime_col
from table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Update t2 Set Datetime = t1.DateTime
   From Table1 t1 Join Table2 t2 On t2.id = t1.id
```