# Update a column of a table using another column of the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables vehicle_table and vehicle_group_table

- vehicle_table --> Has columns --> vehicleid,groupname,groupid
- vehicle_group_table --> has columns --> groupid,groupname

I want to update my vehicle_table's groupid column by joining vehicle_group_table on its common groupname column

```
UPDATE vehicle_table 
    SET vehicle_table.groupid = vehicle_group_table.groupid
    WHERE vehicle_table.groupname = vehicle_group_table.groupname
```

But this seems to be not working.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'But this seems to not be working'? What error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  V
SET
  groupid = VG.groupid
FROM
  vehicle_table V
  JOIN
  vehicle_group_table VG ON V.groupname = VG.groupname
```

You need to correlate the 2 tables via a JOIN. There are other ways with subqueries etc

<strike>Note: **don't** use aliases in destination/target columns in the SET clause as suggested in other answers. It fails in SQL Server</strike> Not in SQL Server 2012 so I think behaviour changed

For a more complicated setup: [SQL update query using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins/982947#982947)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the following syntax in your scenario:

UPDATE TargetTable

FROM SourceTable

SET TargetTableField = SourceTable.SourceTableField

WHERE  TargetTable.Field = TargetTable.Field;

Comment: This is not SQL Server syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
Update vt
Set vt.groupiid = vgt.groupid
from vehicle_table vt
inner join vehicle_group_table vgt
on vt.groupname = vgt.groupname
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
    UPDATE A SET A.groupid = B.groupid 
    FROM vehicle_table A INNER JOIN vehicle_group_table B ON 
    A.groupname = B.groupname
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UPDATE a set a.groupid =b.groupid

from vehicle_table a
inner join 
vehicle_group_table b

on a.groupname = b.groupname
```