# How do I Update a column that is like %another column% in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to run an Update on a table based upon values in another table.

So I have `Table 1` with `Column A`

And I have `Table 2` with `Column B`

I want to run an update so that every row in Column A gets updated with 'RANDOM STRING' if Column A is LIKE Column B.

Pretty simple up to here. However the string in Column B could occur anywhere in the String in Column A.

So the query should run something like this

```
UPDATE Table1
SET ColumnA = 'RANDOM STRING'
WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%Table2.ColumnB%'
```

However no rows get updated when I use this, though the WHERE condition should definitely return results

I am running `SQL server 2008`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins .. or search for Update with Join will solve your problem.

Comment: you are comparing the values from ColumnA to a string "%Table2.ColumnB%"

Comment: @Gutanoth thanks for the reply. How do I reference another column instead of a string. If I remove the apostrophe it returns an incorrect syntax error

Comment: @SumitGupta it's not a duplicate. That other question has 3 joins and is not trying to reference a Like to another Table and another column. It's not even close to being a duplicate

Comment: How about doing a SELECT first, then try the UPDATE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
update table1
set  ColumnA = 'RANDOM STRING'
where ColumnA in  
(select table1.ColumnA from table1 inner join table2 on table1.ColumnA like '%'+Table2.ColumnB+'%')
```

Comment: Legendary. Works great

Comment: Works, but is overkill. You should use `CHARINDEX()`. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5fc52/16

Comment: I would recommend looking into the link @JoseRuiSantos gave you, for use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In MySql,
You can do this.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET ColumnA = 'RANDOM STRING' from table1 , table2
WHERE table1.ColumnA LIKE concat('%',table2.columnb,'%')
```