# Copy data from one column into another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to move data from Column Col11 of DB1.Table1 into Col555 of DB2.Table7, based on a certain condition. How do I do it ? Is there a statement like -

```
select Col11 from DB1.Table1
into Col555 of Db2.Table7
where Col11 = 'Important'
```

Comment: This would be like ETL inside SQL server. But, I'd rather not use an ETL tool for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `COPY` or `INSERT` but `UPDATE`(using JOIN):

```
UPDATE [DB2].[Table7]
SET [Table7].[Col555] = [Table1].[Col11]
FROM [Table1] JOIN [Table7] ON -- add the base for the join here...
WHERE [Table1].[Coll] = 'Important'
```

See this post for more details: [SQL update query using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)

Comment: Getting a linked server error. Because these databases are on two different servers.

Comment: There should be no problem doing cross servers join assuming you have a linked server which was configured correctly. what error?

Comment: making a new post on that

Comment: Here is the error and post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460381/sql-server-error-in-executing-query

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [DB2].[Table7] (Col555)
SELECT [Table1].[Col11]
FROM [DB1].[Table1]
WHERE [Table1].[Coll] = 'Important'
```

--May need .[dbo] or schema name between database and table names.

Answer (score 0):

```
  INSERT INTO DB2.TABLE2(col555)
  SELECT Col11 FrOM DB1.TABLE1
  WHERE  Col11 = 'important'
```