# Transaction with loopback linked server - locking issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server, self-reference

I have two databases `A` and `B`. They are both stored on one database instance. I created a loopback linked server on the instance.

Database `A` contains one table `dbo.Users` and one stored procedure updating `dbo.Users` table. In database `B` I have a query which does two things:

1. Execute the stored procedure from database `A` which updates the `dbo.Users` table.
2. Select data from `dbo.Users` through the linked server.

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC [LinkedServer].A.dbo.UpdateUser
select * from [LinkedServer].A.dbo.Users 
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

When I try to execute this stored procedure I get the following exception only when I set a timeout on the linked server; in other cases the query doesn’t finish:

> ```
> Msg 3971, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:3900000002.
> ```

The reason of this problem is that execution of the `[LinkedServer].A.dbo.UpdateUser` stored procedure creates a transaction which does not allow to make a select statement.

So I decided to add `WITH (NOLOCK)` as below:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC [LinkedServer].A.dbo.UpdateUser
select * from [LinkedServer].A.dbo.Users WITH (NOLOCK)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Then I get this exception:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server " LinkedServer "
>   returned message "Unspecified error". 
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for
>   linked server " LinkedServer " returned message "Query timeout
>   expired".
>  Msg 7311, Level 16, State 2, Line 4 Cannot obtain the schema
>   rowset "DBSCHEMA_TABLES_INFO" for OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for
>   linked server "LinkedServer". The provider supports the interface, but
>   returns a failure code when it is used.

I found information about this exception on [microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/906954). There is information that this error occurs when you try to run distributed queries from a 64-bit SQL Server client to a linked 32-bit SQL Server. In my case it doesn’t make sense because I have a loopback linked server.

The above errors don't occur when the databases are deployed on separate SQL server instances. Any ideas how to omit locks or change the T-SQL to not get exceptions when using a loopback linked server?

Comment: Is there really a need for a self-referencing linked server? Why not refer to the other database by `database_name.schema_name.table_name`?

Comment: @TT For development we have only one server, but in production it's two different servers.  Project database refers to $(RemoteServerToA) which may refer to itself or not.

Comment: Are you sure the Stored Proc in B does not refer to tables in B via the link-server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server " LinkedServer "
>   returned message "Unspecified error".
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server " LinkedServer "
>   returned message "Query timeout expired".
>
> Msg 7311, Level 16, State 2, Line 4 Cannot obtain the schema rowset
>   "DBSCHEMA_TABLES_INFO" for OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked
>   server "LinkedServer". The provider supports the interface, but
>   returns a failure code when it is used.

I have also faced the above mentioned error.

If you are doing loop back linked server and receive the same error then check that any SP using loop back server should be written (Create Procedure)at the end of the script.

If using code from TFS, write create procedure statement of that SP, using loop back linked server in the post deployment.

Simply follow any one of the below mentioned steps:-

1. Copy paste the SP in the end of script. **OR**
2. Don't use loop back server. **OR**
3. If you are using **publish script from TFS** write SP in the Post deployment script (after Data insert into all table).

**These solution worked for me.**