# Insert column from one table to other using Join

Tags: sql-server, join, insert

I need to insert 3 columns from one table to another, using JOIN by 3 fields: name, surname and age

[image]

I need update column  status, status1 and status2  in table_2 with values from table_1

```
IF 

table_1.name = table_2.name
table_1.surname = table_2.surname
table_1.age= table_2.age
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE t2
SET 
 t2.[status]=t1.[status]
,t2.[status1]=t1.[status1]
,t2.[status2]=t1.[status2]
FROM [table_1] t1
INNER JOIN [table_2] t2 
ON (t1.name=t2.name AND t1.surname=t2.surname AND t1.age=t2.age)
```

As you mentioned in comments that these table from different databases, then please change only the two line like.

```
 FROM [yourDataBase1Name].[dbo].[table_1] t1
 INNER JOIN [yourDataBase2Name].[dbo].[table_2] t2
```

Comment: It does not work :(
this 2 tables are from different databases. Maybe that is the reason. Because I have error message 
The multi-part identifier "database.table_2.staus" could not be bound

Comment: exactly not worked if they from diff dbs. i will edit  my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just update the table with Join.
it will be something like this:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.status = t1.status,
    t2.status1 = t1.status1,
    t2.status2 = t1.status2
FROM t2 JOIN t1 on (t1.first_name = t2.first_name AND t1.last_name = t2.last_name AND t1.age = t2.age);
```

Look here for more information:[SQL update query using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3951/1