# update table - multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to update a single column from a backup version of a database.  I've restored the backup to a different db location and am running the following:

```
update table_name
   Set
   column = restoredDB.dbo.table_name.column
From restoredDB.dbo.table_name
Where restoredDB.dbo.table.ID = table_name.ID
```

The following result is returned:

> The multi-part identifier "table_name.ID" could not be bound

The ID field is a primary key, bigint.  I've found many postings on the topic of "multi-part identifier could not be bound" however they don't seem to apply to my situation.  Could someone explain why this is happening and how to correct the error?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need for column refernces is the TableName.ColumnName:

```
update table_name
   Set
   column = table_name.column
From restoredDB.dbo.table_name
Where table.ID = table_name.ID
```

Also, in your `Where table.id =` expression, you do not have any table name `table` in your example query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the tables.  To this:

```
from restoredDB.dbo.table_name
```

add this

```
join table_name on restoredDB.dbo.table.ID = table_name.ID
```

which means that you can get rid of this:

```
where restoredDB.dbo.table.ID = table_name.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

UPDATE table_name
SET table_name.column = restoredDB.dbo.table_name.column
FROM table_name 
JOIN
restoredDB.dbo.table_name.column ON table_name.ID = table_name.ID

Based on [SQL update query using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should resolve the issue.

```
USE [<table_name_DB_Name>]
GO
UPDATE table_name
SET
column = t1.column
From restoredDB.dbo.table_name t1, table_name t2
Where t1.ID = t2.ID
```