# Getting "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error running update query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, insert-update

Please be gentle, I am trying to update the query in sql server but facing an error. Here is my two tables that are in same database and a query furnished below and my requirement is to update the column groupCode in table2 based on table 1 but I am facing the following error:

**Error**

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

**Table 1**

```
**Dept**    **DeptCode**    **GroupName**   **GroupCode**
IT      32      Login-Els       1
IT      32      QC-Els          4
CT      20      Login-OUP       1
CT      20      XML-OUP         2
CT      20      QC-OUP          4
MECH    34      Login-CEN       1
MECH    34      XML-CEN         2
MECH    34      PAGINATION-CEN  3
MECH    34      QC-CEN          4
```

**Table2**

```
**Activity**    **DeptCode**    **Group**
Login-Els       32      NULL
QC-Els          32      NULL
Login-OUP       20      NULL
XML-OUP         20      NULL
QC-OUP          20      NULL
Login-CEN       34      NULL
XML-CEN         34      NULL
PAGINATION-CEN  34      NULL
QC-CEN          34      NULL
```

**SQL**

```
update db1..Activity set 
Groupcode = (
                select groupcode 
                from db1..Groups 
                where DeptCode=32 
                    and Groupname = (
                                     select activity 
                                     from db1..Activity 
                                     where DeptCode=32
                                    )
             )
```

Comment: WHY and has been there in update code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message indicates that one or both of your subquery returned more than one row. That's not allowed as you're using the subqueries as operand of `=`. One possible way to fix the error is by adding `TOP 1` to each of your subquery.

Another possible way to accomplish this kind of update task is by using [`UPDATE ... FROM ... JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins) syntax like so :

```
UPDATE Activity
SET Groupcode = G.groupcode
FROM Activity A
    INNER JOIN Groups G 
        ON A.activity = G.Groupname
           AND A.DeptCode = G.DeptCode
WHERE A.DeptCode = 32
```

Answer (score 1):

error simply suggest you that you inner query return more than one value 
hence sql get confused.so prevent multiple value my using **top cluase**

try this..

```
update db1..Activity set 
Groupcode =(select top 1 groupcode from db1..Groups where DeptCode=32 and 
Groupname =(select top 1 activity from db1..Activity where DeptCode=32))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to always update so that the inner select always returns one row. Your example doesn't really match with the example tables, but maybe this is what you want:

```
update
  Table2
set
  Group = (
    select
      GroupCode
    from
      table1
    where
      table1.DeptCode = table2.DeptCode and
      table1.GroupName = table2.Activity
  )
```

This part doesn't really make sense:

```
Groupname =(select activity from db1..Activity where DeptCode=32))
```

Because you're trying to update the table from itself, if that's really the case, then you can just use:

```
update table2 set GroupName = Activity
```

without using any inner selects.

Comment: Thanks har07, dhaval, jamesZ and all for your great suggestion