# Give a raise to people who work in X city?

Tags: sql

Let's say these are the 2 tables:

```
workers[name, dep_id, salary]
```

and

```
 department[id, name, city]
```

How can I achieve to raise the salary of those who work in a particular city?

I'd only know how to do it if the city was in the workers table (then it'd be just `UPDATE workers SET salary = salary * 1.1 WHERE city = 'X'`), but it doesn't work when the `salary` and `city` are in different tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update query using joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)

Comment: This is done differently in different flavors of SQL, which database backend are you using. IT is important.

Comment: I have to point  out that this design is flawed for many workplaces. Just because the department is located in a city is no guarantee that all employees are. My department is located in a city in Virginia but we have employees who are located in Colorado, Pennsylvania,Texas, Illinois, Maryland, and other cities in Virginia as well as overseas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
UPDATE workers w
SET salary = salary * 1.1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM departments d
              WHERE d.id = w.dep_id
              AND d.city = 'X')
```

You can use also other queries, depending on your specific system.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE w
SET w.salary = w.salary*1.1
FROM workers w
LEFT JOIN department d
ON d.id = w.dept_id
WHERE d.city = 'denver'
```

I believe this will work. Left joining to department will give you the extra columns you're looking for for each row in workers.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    w
SET
    w.salary = w.salary * 1.1
FROM
    workers w
INNER JOIN
    departments d
ON
    w.dep_id = d.id
WHERE
    d.city = 'X'
```

Best and most safe way to do any data update is to first select rows which you want to update.
So First step will be

```
    SELECT (*)  // Select all     
    FROM
        workers w  // From workers
    INNER JOIN
        departments d // and departments 
    ON
        w.dep_id = d.id // where workers dep_id vakue is in 
                        // departments id column 
                        // INNER JOIN get ONLY  that data
    WHERE
        d.city = 'X' // and filter by city name
```

now you can replace select part with

```
 UPDATE
        w  // Update table which name or alias is w
    SET
        w.salary = w.salary * 1.1 / set salary to current salary * 1.1
```

Comment: inner join on workers and departments will return all workers which dep_id are in id column of table departments. Where will filter this result, so we will have only workers for departments which are in city 'X'. now we will update salary for all these workers to current salary * 1.1

Comment: Can you update the answer with the same thing? I'm aware of how SQL works but just a  request to follow community guidelines.

Comment: I believe that now is god enough :)