# SQL How to connect two tables together by a specific column?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables: university and university_list

Table1 - university
[image]

Table2 - university_list
[image]

I added `university_id` into the table 2 and I need to connect the two tables.

If `university_name` from table 1 and `name` from table 2 are identical, get the `id` from table 1 and replace it onto table 2 `university_id`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server? They're totally different databases. If you're using PhpMyAdmin, it must be MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE university_list a 
JOIN university b ON a.name = b.university_name 
SET a.university_id = b.id
```

Comment: THIS WORKED ON THE DOT THANK YOU!

Comment: Is this MySQL syntax?

Answer (score 4):

```
select a.id,b.name from table1 as a
inner join table2 as b
on a.university_name = b.name
```

Above query will return id and name of university if match. Hold both value in variable and pass variable in update query.

```
update table2 set university_id = '$val' where b.name = '$name';
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple join update 
You can update table 2 using below query

```
update ul
set university_id = u.id
from 
  university u inner join university_list ul on ul.name = u.university_name
```

you also can refer to [Join Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)