# MySQL insert into column data from another table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables:

```
   original {ID, FirstName, LastName}
   and
   dummy {ID(NULL), FirstName, LastName}
```

I have to insert into t2.ID the original.ID but only if the FirstName and LastName from both tables are the same. Now, i've tried:

1.Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't2.FirstName' in 'where clause'

```
INSERT INTO dummy (ID)
SELECT ID
FROM original
WHERE dummy.FirstName = original.FirstName
    AND dummy.LastName = original.LastName;
```

2.Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'original.FirstName' in 'where clause'

```
UPDATE dummy
SET ID = original.ID
WHERE dummy.FirstName=original.FirstName
   AND dummy.LastName= original.LastName;
```

3.Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

NOTE: I have to find a way without disableing safe mode.

```
UPDATE dummy
   JOIN original
   ON original.FirstName = dummy.FirstName
       AND original.LastName = dummy.LastName
SET dummy.IDPacient = original.ID
WHERE original.ID <> 0;
```

Now if someone could help me understand what i did wrong in each of these 3 cases and/or give me a better solution, i would much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1 is just plain wrong - you'll insert a new row, not update the existing row.

Version 2 is close, you just need a join to "original":

```
UPDATE dummy
SET ID = original.ID
FROM dummy
INNER JOIN original
  ON dummy.FirstName =original.FirstName
  AND dummy.LastName = original.LastName;
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But there is something off here, i get a syntax error at `FROM` telling me that `is not a valid input at this position`

Comment: I've passed that error eliminating from querry `FROM` and moving `set` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a join on first and last name between the "original" and "dummy" tables and then update the ID

Try this..

```
Update a
Set a.ID = b.ID
From dummy a
Join original b
On a.firstname = b.firstname
And b.lastname = b.firstname
```

You were trying to filter based on columns in the "original" table but it wasn't included in a from clause in your query.

This link might also have some more useful info for you if you need it.
[SQL update query using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)