# Incorrect syntax error for Update-Inner Join statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server and when writing this code I am getting an incorrect syntax error for the "Inner" and also "=" within the SET line. I've looked into this and think everything is set up correctly, can someone point out why if possible?

```
USE [db1]

GO

UPDATE a.[table1] 
INNER JOIN a.[table1] = a.[table2]
ON a.[table1].[field1] = a.[table2].[field1]
SET [field2] = a.[table2].[field2]
WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT #TempTable.[ID] FROM #TempTable)
```

Comment: I doubt you searched very long. First result: [SQL update query using joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have absolutely no idea where you got the syntax for an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` from, but it's pretty messed up. This should be the right code:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.field2 = t2.field2
FROM dbo.table1 t1
INNER JOIN dbo.table2 t2
    ON t1.field1 = t2.field2
WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT [ID] FROM #TempTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  a
SET [field2] = a.[table2].[field2]
from  a.[table1] 
INNER JOIN a.[table1] = a.[table2]
ON a.[table1].[field1] = a.[table2].[field1]
WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT #TempTable.[ID] FROM #TempTable)
```

See if it is working

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
UPDATE a.[table1] 
SET [field2] = a.[table2].[field2]
From a.[table1]
INNER JOIN a.[table2]
ON a.[table1].[field1] = a.[table2].[field1]
WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT #TempTable.[ID] FROM #TempTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update using inner join

```
UPDATE T1
    SET T1.[field2] = T2.[field2]
    FROM a.[table1] AS T1 
    INNER JOIN a.[table2] AS T2
    ON T1.[field1] = T2.[field1]
```