# sql query to get multiplication of two rows of two different tables and insert the answer to one of the two table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have two tables tblemployee, tblEmpSalary. I want to take the MonthlySalary form the tblEmployee and multiply it with the attendance in the tblEmpSalary and insert the answer to the tblEmpSalary table totalsalary column. Anyone kindly help me please.

```
tblEmployee
>EmpId
>Empname
>MonthlySalary

tblEmpSalary
>SalaryId
>EmpId
>Month
>Year
>AttendanceOfCurrentMonth
>TotalSalaryOfMonth
```

I want the TotalSalaryOfMonth to be the

> multiplication of MonthlySalary and AttendanceOfCurrentMonth

for each specific employee

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for Update based on Join conditions.
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins) already answers your question.

`UPDATE A
SET TotalSalaryOfMonth = AttendanceOfCurrentMonth * MonthlySalary
FROM tblEmpSalary A
INNER JOIN tblEmployee B
    ON A.EmpId = B.EmpId`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE tblEmpSalary set TotalSalaryOfMonth=e.MonthlySalary*s.AttendanceOfCurrentMonth
from tblEmployee e join tblEmpSalary s ON e.empId=s.empId
```

Comment: Please mark any one the response as accepted answer when you find the solution..... And good that it worked.... enjoy