# SQL Update statement with Select column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement as below:

```
DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(50)
SET @delimiter=':'
;
WITH CTE AS
( 
    SELECT 
        [pt],
        CAST('<M>' + REPLACE([pt], @delimiter , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) 
        AS [Employee Name XML]
    FROM  [mytable] 
)
SELECT
     [Employee Name XML].value('/M[1]', 'varchar(50)') As [PT],
     [Employee Name XML].value('/M[2]', 'varchar(50)') As [IP],
     [Employee Name XML].value('/M[3]', 'varchar(50)') As [BR]

FROM CTE
GO
```

it returns columns named PT, IP and BR. Now, I want to use these values to update the same table i.e. mytable to set the columns PT/IP and BR. How can I do that in SQL?

Comment: Please add a note on which SQL dialect you are using.

Comment: From the missing semicolons, the `[]` and the `GO` I'm guessing that's for SQL Server and added the tag.

Comment: I think you might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins). It might be usable to achieve what you want (join the CTE to the update).

Comment: You need to output a column to identify each record to update if the combination of PT,IP and BR is not unique.