# Update query with Join SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, join

I have these two tables
[image]
[image]

The first image represents **ObjectData** Table, and the second **ColumnsSet** Table.

In **ObjectData** the ColID attribute represents the foreign key of ColumnID in **ColumnsSet** Table.

I want to update a cell in Data attribute of **ObjectData** for example number 10 to be 20.

query :

```
UPDATE ObjectData SET ObjectData.Data = 'Ahmed'
FROM ColumnsSet
INNER JOIN ObjectData ON ColumnsSet.ColumnID = ObjectData.ColID
WHERE ObjectData.ColID = ColumnsSet.ColumnID
```

What is the correct SQL statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update query using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)

Comment: I have tried this example but it is still not working 
This is my query


"UPDATE ObjectData 
SET ObjectData.Data = 'Ahmed' 
FROM ColumnsSet INNER JOIN ObjectData ON ColumnsSet.ColumnID = ObjectData.ColID
WHERE ObjectData.ColID = ColumnsSet.ColumnID"

Comment: The same issue, 
all Data Cells are updated to the new value 'Ahmed'.
I only want one cell

Comment: Please add any relevant information, and any things you have tried, in the question not in the comments.

Comment: Move your updating table to first 

UPDATE od SET od.Data = 'Ahmed' FROM ObjectData od INNER JOIN ColumnsSet cs ON cs.ColumnID = od.ColID WHERE od.ColID = cs.ColumnID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE a SET a.Data = 'Ahmed'
FROM ObjectData  a 
INNER JOIN ColumnsSet  ON ColumnsSet.ColumnID = a.ColID
```

when you are using inner join it selects data which returns join condition true and not null datas 
there is no need to this 'where  ....' 
but you have to be sure which data will update 
at first use this code and select all data

```
SELECT * 
FROM ObjectData  a 
INNER JOIN ColumnsSet  ON ColumnsSet.ColumnID = a.ColID
```

and then write where clause 
then change it to update

Answer (score 0):

Let me show on example how to update.
At first, we should create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE ObjectData
(
     ID INT,
     CollID INT,
     Data VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE ColumnSet
(
     ColumnID INT,
     ColumnName VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Then insert data:

```
INSERT INTO ObjectData
(
    ID,
    CollID,
    Data
)
VALUES
(   113, -- ID - int
    1, -- CollID - int
    '1' -- Data - varchar(50)
    )
, (114, 5, '')
, (115, 10015, 'Mohamed')
, (116, 20026, 'Abdulghani')

INSERT INTO ColumnSet
(
    ColumnID,
    ColumnName
)
VALUES
(   1, -- ColumnID - int
    'ID' -- ColumnName - varchar(50)
    )
, (5, 'EmployeeID')
, (10015, 'FirsName')
```

And the final step is updating where you should write what rows need to be updated by `WHERE` operator:

```
UPDATE od
 SET od.Data = 'Hey!'
FROM ObjectData  od 
INNER JOIN ColumnSet cs ON cs.ColumnID =od.CollID
--WHERE OD.DATA IN ('1', '10')
WHERE OD.CollID IN (1, 5)
```

You can write in `WHERE` statement any condition to choose your row which will be updated.

```
--Check our update statements:
SELECT
*
FROM ObjectData  od 
INNER JOIN #ColumnSet cs ON cs.ColumnID =od.CollID
WHERE OD.DATA IN ('1', '10')
```