# SQL error "multi-part identifier could not be bound" when updating table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE [cart]
SET    [cart].item_id = [linked_server].[database].[dbo].[linked_cart].item_id
FROM   [linked_server].[database].[dbo].[linked_cart]
INNER JOIN [products] ON [cart].product_id = [products].product_id 
WHERE  [linked_server].[database].[dbo].[linked_cart].sales_id = 'ABC'
  AND  [linked_server].[database].[dbo].[linked_cart].product_name = [products].product_name 
  AND  [linked_server].[database].[dbo].[linked_cart].line_id = [cart].line_id
```

It's complaining when I give the full path to the linked server, and the table `Cart` in the `INNER JOIN` line. The error is

> The multi-part identifier [cart].product_id could not be bound.

It also does this for the linked server tables.

Is there a workaround? The error does go away if I remove the identifiers, but then it changes ALL rows in `Cart` because of ambiguity I'm guessing.

Comment: Do you realize that you don't have a table named (or aliased) "Cart" in your FROM clause?    The error message was a big hint.   If you want to update a table named "Cart", and you need to use a FROM clause to join other tables, you must include "Cart" in the FROM clause.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks, but it's also happening for `[linked_server].[database].[dbo].[linked_cart]` in the WHERE clause, and that table is included in the FROM clause. Is that supposed to be in a JOIN then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to update a table using join, you must include it to FROM as well.

```
UPDATE [cart]
SET    [cart].item_id = lc.item_id
FROM   [cart]
INNER JOIN [products] ON [cart].product_id = [products].product_id 
INNER JOIN [linked_server].[database].[dbo].[linked_cart] lc ON 
         lc.sales_id = 'ABC'
         AND lc.product_name = [products].product_name 
         AND lc.line_id = [cart].line_id
```