# Update SQL Server table with join option

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

As you see the 2 tables, I want to update/sync the data from table `Invoice` to table `HR`.

The scenario is to manually input the data in columns `HR` & `PO Number`, then update with table `Invoice`. I think the idea is to join only data with exist PO Number in table `HR`, no need to get rows if the PO Number does not exist. Also the format of column month looks like a number, so how to get just month in SQL and does not matter the format of date.

[image]

Comment: Please reformulate your question!

Comment: In HR table you don't have year column. So, you maintain only one year of data? What happens in the next year? Data for each month is overridden?

Comment: @fiveelements, the year not a problem here, I need to update with the month

Comment: @avermaet , the question is how to update the HR table?

Comment: You want to create an UPDATE query with JOINS?  If that is your question, why not search for the answer online?  I just did, and I found this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins

Comment: @MedAmin The year is a problem if you want this to work for more than a few more months.

Comment: @Error_2646, yes sure, maybe when I select the data with year, but with update just to sync the data with months and the year will be the current year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If year ***truly*** isn't a problem, then you can do it statically.

But I'd guess you really want to get a year field added to that HR table.

```
UPDATE INVOICE
  FROM HR
 WHERE INVOICE.po_number = HR.po_number
   SET INVOICE.amount = 
           CASE WHEN INVOICE.MONTH = 20190124 THEN HR.JANUARY
                WHEN INVOICE.MONTH = 20190224 THEN HR.FEBUARY
                WHEN INVOICE.MONTH = 20190324 THEN HR.MARCH
                WHEN INVOICE.MONTH = 20190424 THEN HR.APRIL
                WHEN INVOICE.MONTH = 20190524 THEN HR.MAY
                WHEN INVOICE.MONTH = 20190624 THEN HR.JUNE
                WHEN INVOICE.MONTH = 20190724 THEN HR.JULY
                WHEN INVOICE.MONTH = 20190824 THEN HR.AUGUST
                WHEN INVOICE.MONTH = 20190924 THEN HR.SEPTEMBER
                WHEN INVOICE.MONTH = 20191024 THEN HR.OCTOBER
                WHEN INVOICE.MONTH = 20191124 THEN HR.NOVEMBER
                WHEN INVOICE.MONTH = 20191224 THEN HR.DECEMBER
                ELSE INVOICE.AMOUNT
            END;
```

Comment: This query updates amount in Invoice table based on the HR table. This is relatively easier. However, the question was the opposite and that is a bit different: "I want to update/sync the data *from table Invoice to table HR*". Then how this is accepted as an answer?

Comment: @fiveelements in my question I use an example, and the answer given by Error_2646 gave me an idea how to do it using "Case When" so I accept his answer

Answer (score 1):

Use pivot to convert Invoice rows into columns (PO number and months). Then update the HR table by joining with the converted table data.