# How do i perform a conditional update in SQL with data from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to run an update on a column and i'm getting a syntax error on the FROM line connecting the tables

```
UPDATE inv_loc
SET inv_loc.product_group_id = 'TEMP'
WHERE inv_mast_ud.eh_spk LIKE '%T'

FROM
inv_mast_ud
left join inv_loc on inv_mast_ud.inv_mast_uid = inv_loc.inv_mast_uid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WHERE` comes after `FROM`.  I think you want:

```
UPDATE inv_loc
    SET inv_loc.product_group_id = 'TEMP'
    FROM inv_loc JOIN
         inv_mast_ud
         ON inv_mast_ud.inv_mast_uid = inv_loc.inv_mast_uid
    WHERE inv_mast_ud.eh_spk LIKE '%T';
```

Note that I changed the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.  You are updating `inv_loc`, so it makes no sense that that table is the *second* table in a `LEFT JOIN`.

I assume you actually want to filter the rows, so a `LEFT JOIN` is not needed.  Otherwise, you would not need `inv_mast_ud`.

Answer (score 2):

The `WHERE` clause belongs at the end of the update join statement:

```
UPDATE il
SET il.product_group_id = 'TEMP'
FROM inv_loc il
INNER JOIN inv_mast_ud imu
    ON imu.inv_mast_uid = il.inv_mast_uid
WHERE
    imu.eh_spk LIKE '%T';
```

See [SQL update query using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins) for a good canonical answer to your question.