# Struggling to add column and join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently very new to SQL Server and I'm trying to perform a join and add a new column with data to an existing table. My tables are -

1) Enterprise Application Listing (contains Emp name, Emp ID)

2) Enterprise HR listing (contains emp name, emp id, LoginID)

I need to perform a join between the two tables to populate a new column to table 1 with the respective employees LoginID next to their employee ID. This will allow me to use that table for some further analysis. Here is my code that isn't working -

'''UPDATE EnterpriseApplicationListing 
INNER
  JOIN EnterpriseHRlisting 
    ON EnterpriseHRlisting.`emp id` = EnterpriseApplicationListing.`Emp ID`
   SET EnterpriseApplicationListing.LoginID = EnterpriseHRlisting.LoginID'''

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL update query using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server supports a `FROM` clause in `UPDATE`, so you want:

```
UPDATE eal
    SET LoginID = ehl.LoginID
    FROM EnterpriseApplicationListing eal INNER JOIN
         EnterpriseHRlisting ehl
         ON ehl.emp_id = eal.Emp_ID;
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much for the prompt response. I'm still struggling to follow SQL code in a way that makes sense, but I guess that is part of the learning curve.