# SQL Server Update Join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
UPDATE Tickets
    SET Price = 1.13 * Price
FROM Tickets t
JOIN Flights f ON t.FlightId = f.Id
WHERE f.Destination = 'Carlsbad'
```

---

```
UPDATE Tickets
    SET t.Price = 1.13 * t.Price
FROM Tickets t
JOIN Flights f ON t.FlightId = f.Id
WHERE f.Destination = 'Carlsbad'
```

The first code is working perfectly fine, but when I try the second, I get the error

> The multi-part identifier "t.Price" could not be bound.

What's the problem? I think it's more clear the second way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL update query using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.Price = 1.13 * t.Price
FROM Tickets t
JOIN Flights f ON t.FlightId = f.Id
WHERE f.Destination = 'Carlsbad'
```

You need to use `t` (table alias)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that.