# How can I update this column with an aggregate function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

[I calculated a sum for OREB that is unique to every pair of GameId and TeamId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw6Rl.png)

using this query,

[Query Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjL83.png).

```
select DGAM.GameID, HomeTeamID, SUM(OREB) as OREB_Home    
from dimGames as DGAM
join dimPerformance as DPERF on DGAM.GameID = DPERF.GAME_ID and DGAM.HomeTeamID = DPERF.TEAM_ID
group by DGAM.GameID, HomeTeamID
```

Using the results of this query I want to update the null column in this table

[Table called dimGames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2lFb.png).

How can I write an update statement to accomplish this?

Comment: Please don't use images for data, code or errors. Use formatted text. Just use a regular update statement and join your query on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins), I think you want:

```
with agg as (
    select DGAM.GameID, HomeTeamID, SUM(OREB) as OREB_Home
    from dimGames as DGAM
    join dimPerformance as DPERF on DGAM.GameID = DPERF.GAME_ID and DGAM.HomeTeamID = DPERF.TEAM_ID
    group by DGAM.GameID, HomeTeamID
)
UPDATE dimGames dg
    SET dg.OREB_home = agg.OREB_Home
FROM agg
WHERE dg.GameId = agg.GameId and dg.HomeTeamId = agg.HomeTeamId
```