# Count a streak of column values in chronological order and update result in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, gaps-and-islands

Table `Customer`

| ID | Action | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Deal | 26.04.2023 | 15:00 |
| 10 | Meet | 25.04.2023 | 14:15 |
| 10 | Call | 24.04.2023 | 13:00 |
| 10 | Wait | 23.04.2023 | 12:00 |
| 201 | Wait | 15.04.2023 | 14:30 |
| 201 | Wait | 15.04.2023 | 13:30 |
| 201 | Call | 15.04.2023 | 12:30 |
| 201 | Call | 15.04.2023 | 11:30 |
| 201 | Wait | 15.04.2023 | 10:30 |
| 3020 | Wait | 6.10.2021 | 8:00 |
| 3020 | Wait | 5.10.2021 | 8:00 |
| 3020 | Call | 4.10.2021 | 8:00 |
| 3020 | Wait | 2.10.2021 | 8:00 |
| 3020 | Wait | 1.10.2021 | 8:00 |
| 3020 | Wait | 1.10.2021 | 8:00 |

I need to find out a wait-streak for each ID.

Definition for wait-streak is:

1. Starting from `ID`'s newest row, if `Action` is `Wait` then wait-streak = 1
2. If next chronological row with same `ID` has `Action` = `Wait`, wait-streak is added by 1
3. All rows for `ID` are chronologically looped and wait-streak is added by 1 if streak continues
4. If there's are multiple streaks of `Wait`, biggest must be found and value of newest streak must be preserved

In addition to `Date`, also `Time` must be  taken into account. Is it better to combine these into a new date/time column or is there a simple way to use existing columns?

After or during the calculation, results should be updated into a new table. Longest found streak into column `BiggestWaitStreak`, latest streak into column `NewestWaitStreak` and if newest `Action` is `Wait` then column `NewestIsWait` must be set to 1.

After Update new statistics table should look like:

Table `ContactStats`

| ID | BiggestWaitStreak | NewestWaitStreak | NewestIsWait |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 201 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3020 | 3 | 2 | 1 |

I guess best way to achieve this would be utilizing CTE or temporary tables. Personally I prefer CTE. I would be happy to add my work in progress but unfortunately there is none. I don't know where to start.

Any help a highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't show any example of multiple streaks ie series of WAIT followed by CALL then more wait - can that happen? If so this would be solved with a gaps & islands solution.

Comment: Actually this just popped into my mind and I am currently editing the question.

Comment: What did you remove the table formatting for? I've put it back in.  Why does ID 3020 get a value of 2 shouldn't it be 1 as the longest Wait streak is only one row?

Comment: why for `3020`, `BiggestWaitStreak` is `3`? and `NewestIsWait` is `1`?

Comment: That was an error on creating sample data, sorry. Corrected and edited.

Comment: Charlieface, thanks for formatting, looks much nicer. I cannot use my real data atm so I had to manually write a sample and I found it easier to do in external editor. I have to learn to use platform's table editor.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a classic *gaps-and-islands* problem**

The classic solution to find islands of data is to use `LAG` and/or `LEAD` to find the beginning/end of islands, then use a windowed `COUNT` to create an ID per section.

Then it is simply a matter of using more window functions prtitioned over that ID. There is a slight tweak that `NewestIsWait` can be calculated separately using `FIRST_VALUE`.

```sql
WITH PrevValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      PrevAction = LAG(Action) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC),
      NewestIsWait = CASE WHEN
          FIRST_VALUE(Action) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
          = 'Wait' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM YourTable
),
Grouped AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(CASE WHEN Action = 'Wait' AND (PrevAction <> 'Wait' OR PrevAction IS NULL) THEN 1 END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM PrevValues
),
Counted AS (
    SELECT *,
      StreakLength = COUNT(CASE WHEN Action = 'Wait' THEN 1 END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY ID, GroupId)
    FROM Grouped
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Action,
  Date,
  Time,
  BiggestWaitStreak = MAX(StreakLength) OVER (PARTITION BY ID),
  NewestWaitStreak = MIN(CASE WHEN GroupId = 1 THEN StreakLength END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID),
  NewestIsWait
FROM Counted;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/jez5zpPv)

I suggest you consider combining the `Date` and `Time` columns into one.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, looking ingenious. I will try this soon.

Comment: This question has new requirement, UPDATE should be done into a another table. This is smarter in all aspects.

Comment: You probably need a joined update https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins but I suggest you make a new question for that if you are having problems with it